# Executing a closure in place of the condition of an if statement

Tags: swift, closures

The following works. It prints:  *At least one true*

```
let arr = [false, false, false, true, false, false, true, false]

// Variable set by executing a closure...
let hasAtLeastOneTrue: Bool = {
    var x = false
    arr.forEach {
        x = x || $0
   }
    return x
}()

if hasAtLeastOneTrue {
    print("At least one true")
} else {
    print("All false")
}
```

Is it possible to compress the code by eliminating the constant `hasAtLeastOneTrue` and replace the conditional with the closure? Something like:

```
if {CLOSURE CODE}() {
    print("At least one true")
} else {
    print("All false")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The key is to wrap the entire closure invocation with brackets:

```
if ({
    var x = false
    arr.forEach {
        x = x || $0
   }
    return x
}()) {
    print("At least one true")
} else {
    print("All false")
}
```

Though I think this is a lot less readable than `if hasAtLeastOneTrue { ...`. I suggest that you still name your closures, or just use inner functions.

Note that in this case, you can just do:

```
if arr.contains(true) {
    print("At least one true")
} else {
    print("All false")
}
```

Comment: Aha, that's what I needed to know—the syntax used when the closure is used in the condition of the if-statement. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, both: `if ({.....}()) {` and `if ({.....})() {` work.

Comment: @Kaplan Yes, because the closure itself is an expression too, but I feel like `({.....})()` is even harder to understand...